# hooks are not rendering in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

In react, I am trying to use react hooks.I have created one hook which contains a form and I am importing that in class based component and rendering it there. But hooks is not rendering in contact component

//contactushook.js

```
import React from 'react';
const contactUshook = props => {
    return <React.Fragment>
        <form>
            <div>
                <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="enter the     name"></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="enter the email"></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="message" type="text-area" placeholder="Type message here"></input>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </React.Fragment>

}
export default contactUshook;
```

//contact.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import contactUshook from './hooks/contactushook';
class ContactComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>hook</h4>
                <contactUshook></contactUshook>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ContactComponent;
```

Comment: `contactUshook` is not a hook, its just a functional component. If you want to use it then `import ContactUs from '...'` and `<ContactUs />` in the render. React components should start with upper case letters. and you dont need an open and close tag for the component. Also in `contactUshook` you dont need the fragment. Fragments are there for when you have two sibling elements with no root.

Comment: The contactUs is not a hook is just a functional component and they should start with an uppercase letter, otherwise they won't render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty working. You've should name your custom component `<contactUshook>` starting with [capital letter](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component), so React knows that it is custom component and not html tag.

> Note: Always start component names with a capital letter.
>
> React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags. For example,  represents an HTML div tag, but  represents a component and requires Welcome to be in scope.

So this will fix you issue

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ContactUshook from './hooks/contactushook';
class ContactComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>hook</h4>
                <ContactUshook></ContactUshook>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ContactComponent;
```

And as already mentioned, your code does not deal with hooks. You created ordinary components.

Working sample is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so56830637-hg75s)